# Repeat over a collection of Prototypes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a collection of Prototype instances that I ng-repeat over.
The current solution I found is from here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/rdMf0DZHVvE

I basically define a controller on the ng-repeat directive and then initialize the prototype in there something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users" ng-controller="MyUserExtender">
   {{user.name}}
</li>
```

The controller then extends the user:

```
controllers.controller('MyUserExtender', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = new User($scope.user);
});
```

For the complete code please see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5d5v6b5j/

The problem now is, if I change the name of a user via. ng-model for example, the ng-repeat does not update and the user-name that is output stays the same.

Thank you for your input cheers
christoph

Comment: Why do you do new User in the child controller and not when creating the users list?

Comment: well I thought I tried that but it did not work out - turns out it does.
thanks for the hint lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's dead simple, just pass in an array of allready initialized prototypes.

```
var users = [new User({name: 'test'})];

<li ng-repeat="user in users"></li>
```